# Is there a keyboard shortcut to select files of same type in a folder with multiple files types in windows explorer?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, windows-11, file-types

Intended behaviour on Windows 11

---

After clicking on a desired file type for eg .csv; I press some key combination to select all csv files only in that folder. Folder may have multiple files with multiple file types.

**Spoiler**

[multicommander](http://multicommander.com/) has this feature. I'm looking for this feature in windows explorer.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Short of "rolling your own" script, click the `Type` or `Extension` column header to filter on your target file type, then press `Ctrl`+`A`

Comment: As you describe your wish, there is no such feature in Windows File Explorer Windows 11 or 10.